# Moving DNS TXT records

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

My DNS service is cbeyond (MaxASP) and I want to move it to AWS route53 service.

In cbeyond I have 2 fields for TXT records: TXT record (looks like domain) and Record data.
In AWS and other DNS services I have only one field for each record (usually called "Content").

My questions is how can I copy my records to AWS? How it will identify the right data?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the (sub-) domain (there's a field for top at the top when you create a new entry) and providing the right content should be totally sufficient.

My TXT values look something like this, for example for `mandrill._domainkey`:

```
"v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=..."
```